# How Can I Add/use exception handling in a for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

I have a loop in a script. To run the script for 3 processes, one after another. I need to add an exception, if any one process fails it will try for another 2 times, and if fail then print a msg "problem" and then start the next process. here is my loop

```
websites=[]
for i in range(3):
    website = input("Please enter {} no. websites to crawl for image:\n".format(i+1))
    websites.append(website)
for i in range(3):
    crawl = ImageCrawler(websites[i])
    crawl.crawl()
    print("\nFinished crawling website: {}\n".format(websites[i]))
```

Comment: So, write the code to do it. What problem are you having? There's no question in your question (other than the implied "can you write the code for me?", which isn't really on-topic). See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood Hope It is ok, now.

Comment: Do you want to add (raise) an exception or to add exception handling?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Exception handling

Comment: Have you already worked through the Python tutorial, especially https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions?

Comment: @HelloBD rephrasing the title with a question mark doesn't turn it into a question. Seriously, see how to create a [mcve]. Why are you not able to write a loop with an exception in it? What problems are you having?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I was reading this, from here I learnt to accept and continue, but i can not add to try for 2 time (if fail first time)

Comment: If the try-except-block is nested in the for-loop it can be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would work for you, especially if the process is asynchronous and doesn't raise exceptions upon making requests, but the general pattern you could use is this:

```
for _ in range(3) : # maximum 3 attempts
    try:
       performProcess()
       break
    except: pass # you'll probably want to be specific on exception types here
else:
    print("process failed 3 times")
```